# Why do hash joins create a hash table out of the smaller table not the larger one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I ran an explain on this query

```
SELECT
  city.name
  , country.name
FROM
  city
  JOIN country ON
    city.countrycode = country.code

QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------
Hash Join (cost=10.38..139.25 rows=4079 width=20)
 Hash Cond: (city.countrycode = country.code)
 ->  Seq Scan on city (cost=0.00..72.79 rows=4079 width=13)
 ->  Hash  (cost=7.39..7.39 rows=239 width=15)
       ->  Seq Scan on country (cost=0.00..7.39 rows=239 width=15)
```

And I read that the smaller table is always the inner one in this kind of query. But, since we know that hash tables on average give you O(1) access, why is it better to make a small hash table and access it more times, instead of creating a larger hash table and accessing it fewer times? I'm using PostresSQL, but it shouldn't matter becuase this is a fundamental concept for RDBMSes.

Comment: because of the burned of the hash table build

Comment: In both cases the cost is dominated by two (complete) sequential scans. The only difference is the the memory needed for the hash table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hash join algorithm you are referring to basically works by creating a lookup table for one of the tables and then cycling through the other table.  There are double hash algorithms where both tables are hashed, but that is not what you are referring to.

Why cycle through the smaller table?  Consider the work being done:

1. Creating a hash table:  reading and writing one table.
2. Processing the other table:  reading the other table.
3. Final work:  writing out the result set

Note:  This is a simplification of the actual work, assuming that the hash table fits in memory and ignoring hash collisions.

Step (3) is going to be the same amount of work regardless of which table is hashed.

However, the first two are basically:

```
<read one table> + <write one table> + <read the other table>
```

That is, one table is both read and written, so it counts twice.  The other is only read.  You optimize this by processing the SMALLER table as the hash.

In addition, the smaller table is more likely to fit in memory.  And it is less likely to have hash collisions.

So, all in all, it is better to hash the smaller table.